# How to assign a Colourpalette to an output in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, palette

I'm creating an indexed/paletted map in PyQGIS. I want to automate the process since I have many maps to apply this change to, the code is supposed to do the following:

- Reclassify the value to values 0-15;
- Warp: reduce Pixel size and turn GeoTIFF into TIF+TFW (I need it for an old Program afterwards)
- Assign the correct color palette from .clr file

The first two parts of the code work without problems, the assigning of the color palette is my problem.

```
import processing
import os
from qgis.core import  QgsPalettedRasterRenderer

input_path = 'C:/.../'   #(folder path)
output_path = '//.../test/'   #folder path
colourmap_path = 'C:/.../palette_pk25.clr'  #colormap path
target_resolution = 2.5


outputs = {}

#get the path of the file in the 'path' variable
for file in os.listdir(input_path):
    print(file)
    if file.find('.tif') >0:
        
        in_path = input_path+'/'+file
        out_path = output_path+'/'+file
        print(in_path)
        print(out_path)
        if os.path.exists(out_path):
            print("The File "+out_path+" already exists.")
            continue

        # Reclassify values (table)
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': in_path,
            'NODATA': 0,
            'NODATAOPT': False,
            'OTHEROPT': False,
            'OTHERS': 0,
            'RETAB':[1,1,1,2,4,2,5,7,3,8,8,4,9,11,5,12,12,6,13,14,7,15,16,8,17,17,9,18,18,10,19,21,11,22,23,12,24,28,13,29,29,14,30,255,15,0,0,0],
            'TOPERATOR': 1,
            'RESULT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ReclassifyValuesTable'] = processing.run('saga:reclassifyvaluestable', alg_params)
        
        
        #warp map
        alg_params2 = {'INPUT':outputs['ReclassifyValuesTable']['RESULT'], \
            'TARGET_CRS':None,'RESAMPLING':6,'NODATA':None, \
            'TARGET_RESOLUTION':target_resolution,\
            'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,\
            'OPTIONS':'tfw=yes|photometric=palette|profile=baseline',\
            'DATA_TYPE':1,'TARGET_EXTENT':None,'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,'MULTITHREADING':False,'EXTRA':'', \
            'OUTPUT':QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT} #if replaced with output_path it works

       #assign colour map
        outputs['warpreproject'] = processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", alg_params2)
        
        classes = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer.classDataFromFile(colourmap_path)
        renderer = QgsPalettedRasterRenderer(outputs['warpreproject'], 1, classes)
        outputs['warpreproject'].setRenderer(renderer)
```

The code without the assigning of the colourmap works, but I can't figure out to so assign it within the code.
I can manually do it, but that's kinda the thing I wanted to avoid.
I don't generally use Python, so if that impacts the readability of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't figure out how to do this in QGIS, I found a workaround with gimp with the following python Skript:

```
from gimpfu import *

def ewz_load_tif(pattern, palette_name):
    num_files, files = pdb.file_glob(pattern, 1)
    for filename in files:
        image = pdb.file_tiff_load(filename, filename)
        drawable = pdb.gimp_image_active_drawable(image)
        pdb.script_fu_set_cmap(image, drawable, palette_name)
        pdb.file_tiff_save(image, drawable, filename, filename, 0)
    
    
    
    

register(
    "load-cmp-for-tifs",
    "Load Tiffs from a folder and then assign the value from the palette name",
    "Load Tiffs from a folder and then assign the value from the palette name",
    "Martin Specker", "Martin Specker", "2023",
    "Load colormap for indexed TIFF",
    "", 
    [
        (PF_STRING, "inputFolder", "takes input Folder", "\\\\...\\*.tif"),
        (PF_STRING, "Palettenname", "String of Palette", "palette_pk25.gpl")
    ],
    [
        
    ],
    ewz_load_tif, menu="<Image>/Tools")

main()
```